# Disable An Option in angularjs multi select

Tags: html, angularjs, multi-select

Iam using an angularjs multiselect  box like below
[image]

This is my html code

```
 <select multiple ng-options="Language.LangID as Language.LangName for Language in AllLanguages " ng-model="CountryExtraLanguages" multi-select="AllLanguages" ms-options="msOptions2" ng-selected="" ng-disabled=true ></select>
```

I need to disable or hide a specific language (id stored in another variable).
How it possible  ????

I tried `ng-disabled=true` but it diable all the options, I need to hide/disable only one specific option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by adding an **disable when** condition **into ng-options**

for example you can do in this way

```
<select multiple ng-options="Language.LangID as Language.LangName disable when Language.LangID == 1 for Language in AllLanguages " ng-model="CountryExtraLanguages" multi-select="AllLanguages" ms-options="msOptions2" ng-selected="" ></select>
```

Comment: @JIJOMONK.A can you write here how did you do? I made an example where it disables where LangID is 5